# Invalid argument specified while applying a function on an image bands

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I tried standard scaling of each band of an image as follows:

```
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-98.3640625, 36.61967042308436],
          [-98.3640625, 32.86546781020435],
          [-92.91484375000002, 32.86546781020435],
          [-92.91484375000002, 36.61967042308436]]], null, false);
Map.addLayer(aoi);

var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                    .filterBounds(aoi)
                    .filterDate('2019-07-01','2019-07-02')
                    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',90))
                    .select('B.*').toBands();
print (S2);

var normalize = function(image) {
  var names = image.bandNames.map(function(name){
    var col = S2.select(name);
    var out = col.subtract(col.mean()).divide(col.stdDev())});
    return out.toBands()};
  
var normalized = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(normalize).toBands();
print (normalized);
```

However, I got the following error.

Invalid argument specified for ee.List(): function normalize(_0) {
return newF.apply(this, arguments);
}

Can you help me?

Comment: Do you want to do this per band? So for every image every band should be corrected with `col.subtract(col.mean()).divide(col.stdDev())`? Where col.mean() is for example the mean for every band 2 in the collection?

Comment: yes, i want to do it per band separately.

Comment: here is code, https://code.earthengine.google.com/176bb6e5da86f87386a9ab52c3034112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so your code is a bit unusual for Earth Engine.
I would heavily suggest you to do some of the [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials) available. They are pretty good for giving you an overview on how Earth Engine works.

Anyway, here's a more straightforward approach to what you want to do:

```
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                    .filterBounds(aoi)
                    .filterDate('2019-07-01','2019-07-02')
                    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',90))
                    .select("B.*")
print (S2);

// Calculate mean, standard deviation and coefficient of variance
// for all Images in the collection per band
var meanS2 = S2.mean()
var stdDevS2 = S2.reduce(ee.Reducer.stdDev())
var coeffVarS2 = meanS2.divide(stdDevS2)

// Subtract every coefficient of variance by band for
// every image in the collection
var normalized = S2.map(function(image){
  return image.subtract(coeffVarS2).copyProperties(image)
})

print(normalized)
```

It works by first calculating the coefficient of variance (I think that's what you wanted to calculate) for every band in the Image Collection. Then you map (loop) over the Image Collection and subtract this coefficient from every Image in it.

Comment: I would like to re-explain my requirement. Here, I have an image (1830*1830 pixels) of 312 bands is given. I wanted to calculate mean and standard deviation across the bands  and perform standard scaling, `pixel-mean)/std`. Not sure if you did the same??

Comment: Ah yes right. I forgot that you called `.toBands()` on the ImageCollection. If you do not call `.toBands()` my code does exactly what you want it to do. I edited my answer to reflect that

Comment: In my real case, given condition is an image of many bands.

Comment: What do you mean in your real case?

Comment: I have done some processing (not shown due to lengthy code) and got an image with bands, which is to be standardized now.

Comment: So it's not possible for you to keep the bands in seperate Images?

Comment: So, I'm thinking of using ee.ImageCollection.fromImages....and use your code

Comment: also, right function is `(image-mean)/std`. I think you are using `image-mean/std'

Comment: Yes you're right.